# WEB API пользовательские методы

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

Здравствуйте, только разбираюсь с сервисом, не работают кастомно-названные методы

```
public class TasksController : ApiController
{
 IManager m_Realize = new RealizeManager();

    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/<controller>
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetJSON()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

В этом случае не работает не `Get` не `GetJSON`, если убрать `GetJSON` работают `Get` и остальные методы сервиса, обращаюсь `http://localhost:54723/api/Tasks/GetJSON`

И второй вопрос, если не сложно, объясните, что делать с `IRepository Repository`? Я слышал они тут очень явно фигурируют, возможно структура построения у меня не правильная. Сейчас есть:

```
Controllers.AccountController.cs
Controllers.ManagerController.cs
Controllers.TasksController.cs
```

и

```
Realizations.IAccount.cs
Realizations.IManager.cs
Realizations.RealizeAccount.cs
Realizations.RealizeManager.cs
```

Сервис начал использовать т.к методы в action контроллерах типа:

```
public JsonResult OpenTask(int taskId)
    {
        Array values = m_Realize.GetValuesTask(taskId);
        return new JsonResult { Data = values, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

Как я выяснил не приемлемы, поэтому переписываю работу js сервисом. Помогите, пожалуйста, новичку.

Comment: А что значит "не работают"? 404? И вынесите второй вопрос в отдельную тему, он никак не связан с заголовком этой темы.

Comment: @andreycha после добавления в api config config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes() для [Rout атрибутов к методам
запускаю проект, иду на главную открывается XML ошибка:
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
</Error>

может можно как-то игнорировать MapHttpAttributeRoutes для обычного контроллера?

Comment: А `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute()` конфигурировали? Также добавьте в web.config `<system.web><customErrors mode="Off"/></system.web>`, это должно вывести оригинальную ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ошибка, видимо, следующая:

> Multiple actions were found that match the request

Это значит, что запросу api/Tasks отвечают оба get метода: `Get()` и `GetJSON()`. Этого можно избежать, если включить action в роутинг:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "DefaultApiWithAction",
    "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Другие возможные варианты регистрации можно посмотреть тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499794/single-controller-with-multiple-get-methods-in-asp-net-web-api